# Dispatch multiple actions within RxJS + Redux + Axios

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I'm creating a login epic and dispatching multiple actions, the multiple actions are dispatched fine within 'CatchError' but produces an error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." when dispatching the actions within the observable in the 'else' block.

```
export const loginUserEpic = action$ =>
action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOGIN_USER),
    switchMap(({ payload: { email, password } }) => {
      const body = {
        email: email,
        password: password
      };

  return from(axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND}/api/auth/login`, body, config)).pipe(
    map(response => {
      if (response.data.user.is_active) {
        return { type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: response.data };
      } else {
        return of(
          { type: "USER_LOADING" },
          { type: "TOGGLE_MODAL" },
          updateModalData(modalTypes.EMAIL_SENT, "")
        );
      }
    }),
    catchError(err =>
      of({ type: "LOGIN_FAIL" }, createAlert(alertTypes.RED_ALERT, err.data, err.status))
    )
  );
}));
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too familiar with `react-redux` but have you tried returning an array of actions, perhaps like `from([action1, action2])`?

Comment: yep, same problem unfortunately

Comment: It sounds like `createAlert` might be creating a non-serializable action?  Possibly `err.data` is non-serializable?  But I'm not familiar with observables so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: that part works fine actually, it's within the 'else' block that's triggering the error. Have tried returning both from/of observables and just an array of actions without an observable and the error always persists. it only works when one single action is returned like the if block above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used mergemap so I could then return an observable:

```
    export const loginUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOGIN_USER),
switchMap(({ payload: { email, password } }) => {
  const body = {
    email: email,
    password: password
  };

  return from(axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND}/api/auth/login`, body, config)).pipe(
    mergeMap(response => {
      if (response.data.user.is_active) {
        return of({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: response.data });
      } else {
        return of(
          { type: "USER_LOADING" },
          { type: "TOGGLE_MODAL" },
          updateModalData(modalTypes.EMAIL_SENT, "")
        );
      }
    }),
    // takeUntil(actions$.pipe(ofType(CANCEL))),
    catchError(err =>
      of({ type: "LOGIN_FAIL" }, createAlert(alertTypes.RED_ALERT, err.data, err.status))
    )
  );
})
```

);